# Regex get specific location of number in a set of number

Tags: regex

I'm new in regex and need some help. I have a set of a number of length 10, eg. `2145685155`, and need to get the 3rd digit and 6th digit the `4` and `8` in the example and replace both by a symbol hyphen `-` so the output will be `21-56-5155`, I've been searching by a whole day but can't find anything related, I hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

**regex:**

```
^(\d{2})(\d)(\d{2})(\d)(\d{4})$
```

**substitution:**

```
$1-$3-$5
```

### [see demo](https://regex101.com/r/NArv9T/1)